# Clase no ejecuta dos sentencias consecutivas

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo una transación con dos sentencias:
La primera sentencia (`$sql1`) recibe parámetros para insertar registros en una tabla.
La segunda sentencia (`$sql2`) actualiza la misma tabla desde otra tabla.

```
public function grabar($fec, $casa) {
try {
    $dbh = new ConnectDB();
    $sql1 = "INSERT INTO TABLA1 (cod, nom, fec, casa)
             SELECT cod_stud, nom_stud, :fec, :casa
             FROM TABLA2
             WHERE flag1 = 'X'";

$sql2= "UPDATE TABLA1 a INNER JOIN TABLA2 b
        ON a.cod = b.cod
        SET a.nom = b.nom
        WHERE b.flag = 'X'";

$stmt=$dbh->prepare($sql1);
$stmt=$dbh->prepare($sql2);
$dbh->beginTransaction();

$stmt->bindParam(':fec', $fec, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':casa', $casa, PDO::PARAM_STR);

$stmt->execute();
$dbh->commit();
```

El problema es que al ejecutar el código solo se ejecuta `$sql2`, pero si la quito si se logra ejecutar `$sql1`.
Cuál es mi error?

Comment: `String x = "hola"; x = "adios"; System.out.println(x);` Mi variable solo imprime adios, por qué no imprime hola también?? Pues porque has machacado un valor con el otro. Tal vez así lo veas más claro, porque es exactamente lo mismo

Comment: De donde sale `$casaca`? no debe ser `$casa`?

Comment: Por otro lado es mala práctica englobar funciones, métodos y grandes pedazos de código dentro de excepciones. Me ha tocado ver código con cientos de líneas dentro de un try, con 3 o 4 más try - catch (o except) anidados. Resultado: Aplicación descontrolada que se cierra abruptamente y nadie sabe por qué. Las excepciones solo se usan solo en situaciones muy puntuales, incluso lenguajes como **Go** ni siquiera las traen, ellos dicen que: *Ningun caso es justificable como para añadir excepciones en el lenguaje*.

Comment: Edité: es $casa y $fec.

Comment: @Benito-B Pero los querys son diferentes, uno toma los parámetros y el otro no. No deberían sobreponerse como dices.

Comment: Y los string "hola" y "adiós" también son diferentes, y qué? El operador `=` en programación hace una ASIGNACIÓN. Y eso implica borrar el valor anterior y poner el nuevo, no hay más, no hace magia.

Answer (score 1):

Ni idea de qué hace ConnectDB y tampoco lo muestras. Supongo que es la clase donde abres la conexión y demás.

Igual, es muy posible que la variable `$stmt` prepare una instrucción y después la sobreescribes preparando otra. Hasta donde recuerdo, los métodos prepareStatement no concatenan sentencias. Sólo tienes una instrucción cuando haces el binding de variables.